# How to set the monthly subscription to my iOS application

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

i am doing one application.Previously i used the IAP concept and registered the some of the products and used in my application with Auto renewal subscription.So now i want to set the monthly subscription to my total application and i don't need to register the products on IAP. Please help me is it possible or not.If possible how to set the subscription for my application.

Comment: Can you please explain more..What is IAP? Which type of application you making web based or software?

Comment: IAP-In App Purchase.I am making software based application.

Comment: Please provide more detail, as it stands now the question is incredibly difficult to understand.